# ¿Por qué al ejecutar alguno de los dos botones recibo el error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Llevo dos días aprendiendo tkinter y llevo 1h dándole vueltas y no soy capaz de encontrar una solución a este error.
El error que tengo es al ejecutar las ultimas líneas de código (los botones):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x400')
    root.config(bg='#AED8EF')
    text1 = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=40)
    text2 = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=40)
    text3 = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=83)

    text1.config(state="normal", bg='#09A4BF')
    text1.insert(tk.INSERT, "Enter channel name")
    text1.config(state="disabled")
    text1.grid(row=0,column=0)

    text2.config(state="normal", bg='#09A4BF')
    text2.insert(tk.INSERT, "Add word to blacklist")
    text2.config(state="disabled")
    text2.grid(row=1,column=0)

    text3.config(state="normal", bg='#09A4BF')
    text3.config(font=("Times New Roman", 10, "italic"))
    text3.insert(tk.INSERT, "test")
    text3.config(state="disabled")
    text3.place(x=5,y=350)

    def button_command():
        with open('black_list.txt', 'a') as black_list:
            black_list.write(entry1.get())
            entry1.delete(0, tk.END)

    def button_channel():
        with open('twitch_channel.txt', 'w') as channel_file:
            channel_file.write(entry2.get())
            entry2.delete(0, tk.END)

    entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=46, bg='#45A0D1').grid(row=0, column=1)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(root, width=36, bg='#45A0D1').place(x=435,y=29, anchor=tk.CENTER)


    tk.Button(root, text="Add", command=lambda: button_command(), bg='#0DB692').place(x=540,y=18, width=60, height=20)
    tk.Button(root, text="Add", command=lambda: button_channel(), bg='#0DB692').place(x=540, y=0, width=60, height=20)
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.mainloop()

if '__main__' == __name__:
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas los entrys en estas lineas:

```
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=46, bg='#45A0D1').grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2 = tk.Entry(root, width=36, bg='#45A0D1').place(x=435,y=29, anchor=tk.CENTER)
```

Estás creandolos y luego aplicandoles el método grid y place respectivamente. Estos métodos devuelven None, por lo que tu código termina siendo aproximadamente equivalente a:

```
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=46, bg='#45A0D1')
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry1 = None
```

Y algo similar con entry2.

Y por supuesto, la nada misma no tiene el atributo o método get, tal y como dice el error.

Esto de que grid y place (y también pack) devuelven None, aplica a todos los widgets, no solo a los Entrys.

Solución: Crea y ubica los entrys en dos líneas distintas:

```
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=46, bg='#45A0D1')
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

entry2 = tk.Entry(root, width=36, bg='#45A0D1')
entry2.place(x=435,y=29, anchor=tk.CENTER)
```