# no me toma el .get()

Tags: python, tkinter, get

hace poco empecé a programar en Python y me encontré con un problema usando tkinter, quiero tomar los datos de las entradas cuando apreto en el botón registrase pero no se xq no me reconoce el get, he probado de todo pero no se bien cual es el problema.
Me salta este error:

```
 self.entrada3=self.entrada3.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería. Estuve usando StringVar en las entradas pero no encontré solución asi q lo deje como estaba antes

```
import tkinter as tk

class Ventana(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.master.title('Codificador')
        self.master.geometry('500x250')
        self.master.configure(bg='#A2D9CE')
        self.contenedor1()
       
    def nueva_ventana(self):
        self.ventana=tk.Toplevel(bg='#A2D9CE')
        self.ventana.geometry('300x100')
        
        tk.Label(self.ventana, text='¿Esta seguro q desea salir del programa?', bg='#A2D9CE').pack(pady=20)
        self.boton8=tk.Button(self.ventana, text='Aceptar', bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', command=quit,
                                width=10, height=1).place(x=50, y=60)
        self.boton9=tk.Button(self.ventana, text='Cancelar', bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', command=self.ventana.destroy,
                                 width=10, height=1).place(x=170, y=60)

    def contenedor1(self):

        self.cont1=tk.Frame(self.master, bg='#A2D9CE')
        self.cont1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10)
        self.label=tk.Label(self.cont1, text='Menu', bg='#A2D9CE').place(x=5, y=5)
        self.boton1=tk.Button(self.cont1, text='Iniciar sesión', bg='#34495E', 
                                fg='#E5E7E9', height=3, width=10, command = self.contenedor2).pack()
        self.boton2=tk.Button(self.cont1, text='registrarse',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', height=3, width=10,
                                command=self.contenedor3).pack()
        self.boton3=tk.Button(self.cont1, text='Salir',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', height=3, width=10,
                                command=self.nueva_ventana).pack()

    def contenedor2(self):
        self.cont2=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Ingrese los datos')
        self.cont2.place(x=120, y=15, height=220)
        tk.Label(self.cont2, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Usuario').place(x=5, y=12)
        tk.Label(self.cont2, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Contraseña').place(x=5, y=45)
        self.entrada1=tk.Entry(self.cont2).pack(pady=10, padx=80)
        self.entrada2=tk.Entry(self.cont2).pack(pady=8, padx=80)
        self.boton4=tk.Button(self.cont2, text='aceptar',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9'
                                ).place(x=40, y=120, width=75, height=30)
        self.boton5=tk.Button(self.cont2, text='cancelar',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', command=self.cont2.destroy
                                ).place(x=170, y=120, width=75, height=30)

    def contenedor3(self):
        self.cuad1=tk.StringVar()
        self.cont3=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Ingrese los datos')
        self.cont3.place(x=120, y=15, height=220)
        tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Nombre').place(x=5, y=5)
        tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Usuario').place(x=5, y=35)
        tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Contraseña').place(x=5, y=65)
        tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Correo').place(x=5, y=95)
        tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Key').place(x=5, y=125)
        self.entrada3=tk.Entry(self.cont3, textvariable = self.cuad1).pack(pady=5, padx=80)
        self.entrada4=tk.Entry(self.cont3).pack(pady=6, padx=80)
        self.entrada5=tk.Entry(self.cont3).pack(pady=6, padx=80)
        self.entrada6=tk.Entry(self.cont3).pack(pady=6, padx=80)
        self.entrada7=tk.Entry(self.cont3).pack(pady=6, padx=80)
        self.boton6=tk.Button(self.cont3, text='Aceptar',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', command= self.datos_usuario).place(x=35, y=165, width=80, height=25)
        self.boton7=tk.Button(self.cont3, text='Cancelar',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9',
                                command=self.cont3.destroy).place(x=155, y=165, width=80, height=25)
        
        

    def datos_usuario(self):
        self.entrada3=self.entrada3.get()
        self.usuario=self.entrada4.get()
        self.contraseñao=self.entrada5.get()
        self.correoo=self.entrada6.get()
        self.key=self.entrada7.get()
        print(self.nombre)

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    root=tk.Tk()
    app=Ventana(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Esta respuesta que dí responderá tu duda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/531178/por-qu%c3%a9-al-ejecutar-alguno-de-los-dos-botones-recibo-el-error-attributeerror/531190#531190

Comment: muchas gracias, me resolviste el problema

Comment: De nada Ezequiel c: