# colocar en un lugar especifico un boton

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hola intente poner en un lugar especifico 50,50 de un programa un botón el botón funciono lo que no funciono fue el .place el error trataba de que no reconocía el .place entonces si así no funciona como se supone que debo poner un botón en un lugar especifico.

Código a continuación:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk
raiz=Tk()
raiz.geometry("700x350")
raiz.resizable(0,0)
boton = ttk.Button(raiz, text="boton").pack(pady=10)
boton.place(x=50, y=50)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'place'

Comment: El error se debe a que la variable boton vale None a la hora de hacer el place. Otra persona tuvo un error por los mismos motivos, y la solución es la misma para vos también: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/531178/por-qu%c3%a9-al-ejecutar-alguno-de-los-dos-botones-recibo-el-error-attributeerror/531190#531190 . El error que aclaro en esa respuesta es con Entrys, pero como digo más abajo, aplica a todos los widgets.

Comment: De cualquier modo. Para que usas pack si luego piensas usar place?