# Botón que cuente las veces presionado en tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Buenas mi problema es que tengo que hacer un botón que que cuando se presione incremente el valor, y que a su ves se muestre en la etiqueta numeros_cafes1

```
from tkinter import *

def incrementar():
    valor = int(numeros_cafes1['text'])
    numeros_cafes1['text'] = f"{valor + 1}"

def ventana_cafe():
    nueva_ventana_cafes = Toplevel()
    nueva_ventana_cafes.geometry("500x400")
    

    cafe1 = Label(nueva_ventana_cafes, text='tipo de cafe 1').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    boton_cafe1_mas = Button(nueva_ventana_cafes, text='+', command=incrementar).grid(row=1, column=0)
    numeros_cafes1 = Label(nueva_ventana_cafes, text='0').grid(row=1, column=1)
    boton_cafe1_menos = Button(nueva_ventana_cafes, text='-').grid(row=1, column=3)
```

Cuando presiono el botón que tiene que sumar me dice que la variable no esta definida.
Que podría hacer

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta resuelto, aunque quizás no es lo mas estético que este pero funciona, les comparto el código de como lo deje

```
valor = 0

def ven_cafe():
    nueva_ventana_cafes = Toplevel()
    nueva_ventana_cafes.geometry("500x400")
    
    def incrementar():
        global valor
        valor += 1
        numeros_cafes1 = Label(nueva_ventana_cafes, text=valor).grid(row=1, column=1)
    cafe1 = Label(nueva_ventana_cafes, text='tipo de cafe 1').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    boton_cafe1_mas = Button(nueva_ventana_cafes, text='+', command=incrementar).grid(row=1, column=0)
    boton_cafe1_menos = Button(nueva_ventana_cafes, text='-').grid(row=1, column=3)
```

Comment: Me parece poco optimizado crear un nuevo label cada vez que quieras sumar uno la la variable. O sea si apreto el botón 100 veces aparecen 100 labels. Te recomiendo leer esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531190/158880