# Al utilizar .get con una variable combobox me tira un error que get no esta definido e tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Buenas estoy heciendo un programa sencillo donde quiero utilizar combobox pero al querer obtener el valor usando .get me tira un error diciendo que get no esta definido

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

venta = Tk()

def imprimir():
    
    Label(venta, text= eleccion.get()).grid(row=0,column=1)

eleccion = ttk.Combobox(venta, values=['cafe1','cafe2','cafe3']).grid(row=0, column=0)

boton = Button(venta, text='boton', command= imprimir).grid(row=1, column=0)
venta.mainloop()
```

Este es el código y estado leyendo y viendo vídeos pero a todos no les aparece mi error y no se que hacer

Comment: Estás seguro de que ese es el error? Tal como está tu código, debería de dar algo como `NoneType object has no attribute get`.

Comment: Hay una diferencia entre el error que te estoy mencionado (que significa que estás intentando acceder a un atributo inexistente) y que algo no esté definido (que significa que no existe la variable).

Comment: Me muestra esto:
File "prueba.py", line 10, in imprimir
    Label(venta, text= eleccion.get()).grid(row=0,column=1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Espero que esta respuesta responda a tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531190/158880. En la respuesta hablo sobre Entrys, pero también aplica a los Combobox. Pienso hacer una pregunta + respuesta más general para orientar mejor a todos los usuarios que están teniendo este tipo de error.