# Intento obtener el texto de un objeto de tipo Entry desde una funcion me da error y al imprimir su tipo desde esa funcion me dice NoneType, ¿Por qué?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar y me diga porque no puedo acceder al widget Entry llamado entrada al cual llamo desde una funcion para obtener el contenido de lo que supuestamente se esta escribiendo en pantalla?, esta llamada la activo al presionar un boton.
Aquí les adjunto unas imagenes de mi codigo. Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuacion les muestro el compilado del programa, todo funciona correctamente excepto cuando quiero acceder a ese widget entrada que es donde ingreso el texto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la ventana donde tengo problemas al introducir texto a la entrada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui al presionar aceptar en el codigo puse que me muestre el tipo o la clase a la que pertenece mi variable entrada la cual declare con un objeto de tipo Entry pero aqui me dice que no tiene tipo(NoneType)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tres cosas: 1- El código va como texto, [formateado](/help/formatting). Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880. Segundo, None también es un objeto en Python (de tipo NoneType). Decir que no es de ningún tipo (al menos en python) es falso. 3- El error se debe a que estás haciendo variable = widget(...).place(...). Por favor lee esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531190/158880

Comment: Muchas gracias, pude solucionar mi problema gracias al ultimo link que me proporcionó,  fue de mucha ayuda, mil gracias, y con respecto a lo del codigo lo siento no lo sabía, soy nuevo en la comunidad y no sabia sobre que se debe colocar en texto antes que en imagenes.