# ¿Por qué el widget LabelFrame no se muestra?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy tratando de mostrar un LabelFrame pero no se muestran, a pesar de utilizar el método pack().

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

Root = tk.Tk()

labelFrame = tk.LabelFrame(Root, text = "Label Frame").pack()

Label = tk.Label(labelFrame, text = "Label").pack()
```

[image: ventana resultante]

Answer (score 0):

#### Explicación

El error se debe a que cuando haces `elwidget.pack()` en la variable se guarda None. Esto es por que primero creas el widget, y luego le aplicas el método pack. El método pack devuelve None.

O sea, que cuando creas el label, la variable labelframe vale None, siendo el código equivalente a:

```
Label = tk.Label(None, text = "Label").pack()
```

Y en este caso None significa "creá el widget en la ventana raiz".

En resumen, el LabelFrame se está creando, pero es tapado por el Label que se crea fuera de este.

#### Solución

Como widget.pack() devuelve None, lo mejor es crear el widget en una linea y ubicarlo en otra.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

Root = tk.Tk()

labelFrame = tk.LabelFrame(Root, text = "Label Frame")
labelFrame.pack()

# en realidad, para solucionar el error alcanza con corregir arriba
# peeero esto es buena idea para evitar errores futuros.
Label = tk.Label(labelFrame, text = "Label")
Label.pack()
```

#### Lectura recomendada

Este tipo de error es muy frecuente y le he dado respuesta antes. Aquí te la dejo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531190/158880