# ¿Por qué mi ENTRY me da siempre NONE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Mi ENTRY de TKINTER, cuando le coloco cualquier campo con el teclado, me arroja NONE. ¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Incluso le puse `print(type(campo))`

La idea es que verifique que el usuario sea "master cesar" y la clave "1234" para que pueda acceder a la siguiente pantalla del administrador.

```
from distutils.cmd import Command
from email.errors import MessageParseError
from pydoc import text
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

master = "cesar"
psw = "1234"
def ingresar():
        if campo == master:
            print("acceso permitido")
        else:
            print("acceso denegado")
        

root = Tk()
root.title("Sistema Administrativo SCORPION")
root.geometry("600x600")
root.config(bg="white")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/Cesar/Documents/Programacion coco/SISTEMA ADM SCORPION/logo.ico")
root.resizable(width=0, height=0)
image = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/Cesar/Documents/Programacion coco/SISTEMA ADM SCORPION/imageonline-resizegif-4299917.gif')
image_lab = Label(root, image=image, bg="white").place(x=220, y=400)

bandazul = Label(bg="blue",width=100, height=-3).place(x=0, y=310)
bandazul2 = Label(bg="blue",width=100, height=-3).place(x=0, y=340)
bandazul3 = Label(bg="blue",width=100, height=-3).place(x=0, y=370)

usuario = Label(text= "Usuario", font=("rockwell", 15),fg="blue", bg="white").place(x=10, y=150)
contrasena = Label(text= "Contraseña", font=("rockwell", 15),fg="blue", bg="white").place(x=10, y=200)
creadopor = Label(text= "Creado por Cesar prado", font=("rockwell", 8),fg="blue", bg="white").place(x=0, y=580)

entrada = StringVar()
campo = (Entry(root, textvariable=entrada, width=45)).place(x=150, y=155)
print(type(campo))

entrada2 = StringVar()
campo2 = (Entry(root, text="1234", width=45, show="*")).place(x=150, y=205)


boton1 = Button(root, text="Ingresar", font=("rockwell", 15), foreground="blue", command=ingresar).place(x=180, y=250)
boton2 = Button(root, text="Salir", font=("rockwell", 15), foreground="blue", command=root.destroy).place(x=330, y=250)

titulo = Label(text= "Bienvenido al Sistema Administrativo Scorpion", font=("Consolas", 15),bg="white", fg="blue").place(x=60, y=40)
subtitulo = Label(text= "Ingrese las credenciales", font=("Consolas", 15),bg="white", fg="blue").place(x=160, y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: En esta respuesta explico lo que sucede, ojala te sirva! https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531190/158880

Comment: Otra cosa, no podes comparar un entry con un string. Eso siempre va a ser falso, ya que no son lo mismo. Si queres obtener el texto del entry tenes que hacer elentry.get()

Comment: @DanteS. muchas gracias por la aclaración y por el link donde explicas, ya reviso