# no puedo usar config en funciones tkinter

Tags: python

Hola amigos estoy empezando con tkinter y les
traigo este sencillo código para mostrar mi problema:

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
root.geometry("500x300+300+100")

contador = 0

def contar():
    global contador
    contador +=1
    pantalla['text']=contador
    


pantalla=Label(root,width=7,height=2,font='consolas 30',
      text=0,relief=SUNKEN).pack()
button= Button(root,text='boton',
               command=contar,font='consolas 15').pack()


root.mainloop()
```

#############################################################################33
cuando trato de cambiar el texto del label, no me permite
hacerlo de ninguna de estas 3 formas:

forma 1:

```
contador = 0

def contar():
    global contador
    contador +=1
    pantalla['text']=str(contador)
```

error1:
pantalla['text']=contador
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

######################################################################
forma 2:

```
def contar():
    contador = int(pantalla['text'])
    contador +=1

error 2:
contador = int(pantalla['text'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

##################################################################
forma 3:

```
contador = 0
    contador +=1
    pantalla.config(text=contador)
```

error 3:
pantalla.config(text=contador)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
###################################################################
Así me pasa todo el tiempo cada vez que trato de modificar
los atributos de un label, botones o lo que sea, no me deja usar config
dentro dentro o fuera de la función, ya sea con números o cadenas de texto.
He probado con distintas versiones de Python y siempre es así, y es muy
frustrante ver que en los tutoriales si lo pueden hacer y yo no.
Pueden ayudarme ??

```
introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531190/158880

Comment: Presenyto el mismo problema, he intentado combiar las versiones de Python pero aun asi me pasa lo mismo, en internet no he encontrado como soliucionarlo y en la documentacion no hay un punto donde hable de ello.
¡Ayuda, Por favor!