# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid' en Sublime Text 3, programando con Python

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Buenos días Comunidad!

Tengo un problema con esta parte del código:

```
varOpcion=IntVar()
    miFrame3=Frame(root)
miFrame3.pack()

Label(root, text="Serie").pack()

botonA=Radiobutton(root, text="A", variable=varOpcion, value=1, command=imprimir).pack()
#botonA.place(x=10,y=10)
botonA.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

botonB=Radiobutton(root, text="B", variable=varOpcion, value=2, command=imprimir).pack()
#botonB.place(x=110,y=10)
botonB.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

botonC=Radiobutton(root, text="C", variable=varOpcion, value=3, command=imprimir).pack()
#botonC.place(x=210,y=10)
botonC.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

etiqueta=Label(root)
etiqueta.pack()
```

Básicamente, lo que yo quiero es poder acomodar los botones de forma horizontal, no vertical, así cuando abro la ventana del programa, aprovecho más el espacio ancho. Probé con el atributo grid, y place (Los dejé algunos con "#" porque simplemente no quería borrarlos y tenerlos anotados para otra cosa en el futuro, pero no consigo ni siquiera malcolocarlos, solo me aparece el error de

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Programas\Sublime text 3\Sublime Text 3\Saves\Interfaz\Interfaz.py", line 264, in 
botonBendita.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'

Comment: Mira esta respuesta y entenderás que pasa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531190/158880. Estoy considerando la idea de hacer una autorespuesta para hacer mas facil encontrar la causa.

Comment: Además, estás tratando de ubicar dos veces el mismo widget de dos formas distintas. Tendrás que optar por una de las dos.

Comment: Ya hice una autorespuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/579416/158880

Comment: Ahí lo pude corregir, justo vi que había puesto esto miFrame3=Frame(root) miFrame3.pack() y borré el .pack que por lo que entendí, era el atributo que me estaba imposibilitando las cosas, luego lo acomodé con place.(x="numero" e y="numero"), muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: De nada compa c: