# 'NoneType object has no atribute ...' cuando trato de acceder a un método de un widget Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente código:

```
import tkinter as tk

def mifuncion():
    print(entrada.get())

root = tk.Tk()

entrada = tk.Entry(root).pack()

entrada.bind("<Return>", myfuncion)
```

Que produce el error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Hice algunas pruebas, y me di cuenta que esto ocurre siempre que intento acceder a un método deL objeto entrada. A que se debe y como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explicación

El error se encuentra al momento de crear el Entry, justo en esta linea:

```
entrada = tk.Entry(root).pack()
```

Cuando escribes de esta forma, estás haciendo algo parecido a esto:

```
entrada = tk.Entry(root)
entrada = entrada.pack()
```

Y, como el método pack devuelve None, la variable entrada, en lugar de almacenar nuestro widget, guarda None, que en Python es el valor que representa la ausencia de un valor. Y claro, la nada misma no tiene los métodos que tiene un Entry.

Esta caracteristica, no es unica de pack. De hecho, pack, grid, place y los demás métodos de los widgets de tkinter NUNCA devuelven el widget desde el que son llamados.

#### Solución

Simplemente, ponemos una linea de código con la creación del widget y en otra lo ubicamos.

```
entrada = tk.Entry(root)
entrada.pack()
```

#### Por que esta autorespuesta

He visto muchas preguntas que se deben a esta causa. Por lo que decidí crear esta autorespuesta para responder a todas las dudas pasadas, presentes y futuras sobre el tema.

Sospecho que esta costumbre es transmitida a travéz de tutoriales o cursos que, si bien no cometen este error, si utilizan una forma de programar muy similar a la mencionada más arriba, solo que lo aplican a widgets a los que no se querrá acceder más adelante. Ejemplo:

```
Label(root).pack()
entrada = Entry(root)
entrada.pack()
```