# No puedo operar un valor como entero de una entry tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

buenas tardes, he intentado de muchas formas obtener un valor entero de una entry de Tkinter sin resultado, he probado algunos metodos que vi en el foro, como IntVar, .get, pero nada no logro hacerlo funcionar. El codigo lo que busca es calcular cuanto es el perimetro de unas ventanas (objetos previamente establecidos), y en base a eso mostrarte cuantos tubos de (200cm) necesitarias, y cuanto te sobraria. Aunque de momento me estoy concentrando en hacer funcionar la ventana de entrada, sin exito jajaja.

```
from Ventana import Ventana
def calcular():
    entra1=int((entrada1.get()))
    perimetro1=tipoRectangulo.get_perimetro()
    perimetro2=tipoRectangulo2.get_perimetro()
    perimetro3=tipoRectangulo3.get_perimetro()
    perimetro4=tipoTrianRectangulo.get_perimetro()
    perimetro5=tipoTrianIsosceles.get_perimetro()
    x1=entra1*float(perimetro1)
    x2=entra2*float(perimetro2)
    x3=entra3*float(perimetro3)
    x4=entra4*float(perimetro4)
    x5=entra5*float(perimetro5)
    total=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5
    return total
Raiz=Tk()
entra1=();entra2=();entra3=();entra4=();entra5=()
Raiz.title("Calculador para sellante")
Raiz.resizable(1,1)
Raiz.geometry("500x300")
etiquetaprincipal=Label(Raiz,text="Ingresa la cantidad de ventanas").grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta1=Label(Raiz, text="Rectangulo 1.5x1.5").grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada1=Entry(Raiz).grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta2=Label(Raiz, text="Rectangulo 2.5x0.80").grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada2=Entry(Raiz, textvariable=entra2).grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta3=Label(Raiz, text="Rectangulo 1.5x2.5").grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada3=Entry(Raiz, textvariable=entra3).grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta4=Label(Raiz, text="Triangulo Rectangulo 2.15x0.75").grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada4=Entry(Raiz, textvariable=entra4).grid(row=4,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta5=Label(Raiz, text="Triangulo Isosceles 0.8x1.5 Base y Altura").grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada5=Entry(Raiz, textvariable=entra5).grid(row=5,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
tipoRectangulo=Ventana("Rectangulo",1.5,1.5,0,6)
tipoRectangulo2=Ventana("Rectangulo",2.5,0.8,0,6.6)
tipoRectangulo3=Ventana("Rectangulo",1.5,2.5,0,8)
tipoTrianRectangulo=Ventana("TrianguloRectangulo",2.15,0.78,2.29,5.24)
tipoTrianIsosceles=Ventana("TrianguloIsosceles",0.8,2.41,2.41,5.62)
etiqueta6=Label(Raiz,text="Resultado").grid(row=6,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(Raiz, text="Calcular",command=calcular).grid(row=7,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada6=Entry(Raiz, state=DISABLED, textvariable=calcular).grid(row=6,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)


Raiz.mainloop()



        
class Ventana ():
    def __init__(self,tipo,lado1,lado2,lado3,perimetro):
        self.__tipo=tipo
        self.__lado1=lado1
        self.__lado2=lado2
        self.__lado3=lado3
        self.__perimetro=perimetro
    #Getters
    def get_tipo(self):
        return self.__tipo
    def get_lado1(self):
        return self.__lado1
    def get_lado2(self):
        return self.__lado2
    def get_perimetro(self):
        return self.__perimetro
    def get_lado3(self):
        return self.__lado3
    #Setters
    def set_tipo(self, tipo):
        self.__tipo = tipo
    def set_lado1(self, lado1):
        self.__lado1 = lado1
    def set_lado2(self, lado2):
        self.__lado2 = lado2
    def set_perimetro(self, perimetro):
        self.__perimetro = perimetro
    def set_lado3(self,lado3):
        self.__lado3 = lado3
```

Comment: No se como te fue con los intvar, pero para el código actual, esto responde a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/579415/158880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios problemines...

Por un lado, estás declarando la variables tipo "entra", con:

```
entra1 = ()
```

con lo que creas una `tupla`, que luego intentas multiplicar por un número decimal, lo que no lleva a buen término.

Otro problema serio, es la declaración de los elementos del `frame`, que haces así:

```
etiquetaprincipal=Label(Raiz,text="Ingresa la cantidad de ventanas").grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
```

cuando tienes funciones enlazadas, la variable toma el valor devuelto por la última de ellas, en este caso **grid()**... que no devuelve nada, por lo que tu elemento siempre tiene valor "`NoneType`", debes hacerlo así:

```
etiquetaprincipal=Label(Raiz,text="Ingresa la cantidad de ventanas")
etiquetaprincipal.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Aparte de esos errores, agregué el la función **calcular**, dos lineas, una para pasar el "`entry`" **entrada6** a "`enable`", y otra para asignarle el valor obtenido.

Veamos como quedó:

```
def calcular():
    entra1=int((entrada1.get()))
    perimetro1=tipoRectangulo.get_perimetro()
    perimetro2=tipoRectangulo2.get_perimetro()
    perimetro3=tipoRectangulo3.get_perimetro()
    perimetro4=tipoTrianRectangulo.get_perimetro()
    perimetro5=tipoTrianIsosceles.get_perimetro()
    x1=entra1*float(perimetro1)
    x2=entra2*float(perimetro2)
    x3=entra3*float(perimetro3)
    x4=entra4*float(perimetro4)
    x5=entra5*float(perimetro5)
    total=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5

       # cambiamos el estado del "entry"
    entrada6['state'] = 'normal'

       # escribimos el resultado
    entrada6.insert( 0,str(total) )
    return total


Raiz=Tk()

   # cambiamos de "=()" a (=0) 
entra1=0;entra2=0;entra3=0;entra4=0;entra5=0
Raiz.title("Calculador para sellante")
Raiz.resizable(1,1)
Raiz.geometry("500x300")
etiquetaprincipal=Label(Raiz,text="Ingresa la cantidad de ventanas")
etiquetaprincipal.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta1=Label(Raiz, text="Rectangulo 1.5x1.5")
etiqueta1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada1=Entry(Raiz)
entrada1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta2=Label(Raiz, text="Rectangulo 2.5x0.80")
etiqueta2.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada2=Entry(Raiz, textvariable=entra2)
entrada2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta3=Label(Raiz, text="Rectangulo 1.5x2.5")
etiqueta3.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada3=Entry(Raiz, textvariable=entra3)
entrada3.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta4=Label(Raiz, text="Triangulo Rectangulo 2.15x0.75")
etiqueta4.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada4=Entry(Raiz, textvariable=entra4)
entrada4.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
etiqueta5=Label(Raiz, text="Triangulo Isosceles 0.8x1.5 Base y Altura")
etiqueta5.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada5=Entry(Raiz, textvariable=entra5)
entrada5.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

tipoRectangulo=Ventana("Rectangulo",1.5,1.5,0,6)
tipoRectangulo2=Ventana("Rectangulo",2.5,0.8,0,6.6)
tipoRectangulo3=Ventana("Rectangulo",1.5,2.5,0,8)
tipoTrianRectangulo=Ventana("TrianguloRectangulo",2.15,0.78,2.29,5.24)
tipoTrianIsosceles=Ventana("TrianguloIsosceles",0.8,2.41,2.41,5.62)

etiqueta6=Label(Raiz,text="Resultado")
etiqueta6.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
boton = Button(Raiz, text="Calcular",command=calcular)
boton.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
entrada6=Entry(Raiz, state=DISABLED, textvariable=calcular)
entrada6.grid(row=6,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

Raiz.mainloop()
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Un pequeño detalle. Las variables entra referencian a una tupla, no una lista. En Python, las tuplas, como toda secuencia, se pueden multiplicar

Comment: @DanteS. Perdón maestro y gracias, pregunta porqué me sale error cuando intento multiplicar?.TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: De nada, no hay por que disculparse xD. Y mi error, ahí me equivoqué, en este caso no se puede multiplicar, ya que no tiene sentido sumar una secuencia 1.5 veces por ejemplo

Comment: Ahh, entiendo, el problema es con los decimales, mil gracias!!!